# "word-wrap" functionality

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to develop a PHP functionality where I have an array and a maximum character count.

Return a collection of strings where each string element represents a line that contains as many words as possible, with the words in each line being concatenated with a single '-'. The length of each string must not exceed the maximum character length per line.

Your function should take in the maximum characters per line and return a data structure representing all lines in the indicated max length.

Examples:

```
words1 = [ "The", "day", "began", "as", "still", "as", "the",
          "night", "abruptly", "lighted", "with", "brilliant",
          "flame" ]
```

wrapLines(words1, 13) "wrap words1 to line length 13" =>

```
[ "The-day-began",
    "as-still-as",
    "the-night",
    "abruptly",
    "lighted-with",
    "brilliant",
    "flame" ]
```

What I tried so far is:

```
foreach ($words1 as $i => $word) {
            $a = '';
            if($i!= 0 && strlen($a) <= $lineLength1_1){
                 $a = $a.'-'.$word;
            } else {
                 $a = $word;
            }
            echo $a;
        }
```

The result I get is.

```
The-day-began-as-still-as-the-night-abruptly-lighted-with-brilliant-flame
```

Can someone please help me how to check for the count based on condition and then break into next array key as result?
Thanks.

Comment: In your code, where is your array ?

Comment: I have displayed only strings as I am not able find a way to break this as per the max count.

Comment: Hint: As the max length is 13, so you should go thru the string array and concat the n element, n+1 element, n+2 element and so on until the string length (including the hypens) are more than 13 (then do not include the last element) , then concat them together and push it into a new array , then proceed to the next element(s). Simple, right ?

Comment: @KenLee suppose the condition is "if current word would exceed line length, include on next row", how would we handle e.g. "interdimensional" with a 13 char cap? Also, OP, the phrase "_Your function should take..._" sounds like you're working an assignment, so I'm shy to spell out the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's `wordwrap()` function to help with this:

```
// $a is an array of strings, $line_length is the max line length
function wrap( $a, $line_length ) {          
    $r = array_map( 
        function($s) {
            return str_replace( ' ', '-', $s ); // Replace spaces with dashes
        },
        // Rewrap $a by first joining it into a single string, then explode on newline chars into a new array
        explode( "\n", wordwrap(join(' ', $a), $line_length ) )
    );
    
    return $r;
}

$words1 = [ "The", "day", "began", "as", "still", "as", "the",
          "night", "abruptly", "lighted", "with", "brilliant",
          "flame" ];

print_r( wrap( $words1, 13 ) );
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The-day-began
    [1] => as-still-as
    [2] => the-night
    [3] => abruptly
    [4] => lighted-with
    [5] => brilliant
    [6] => flame
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your teacher disallows you to use built-in PHP function such as wordwrap(), then you may use the following :

1. loop over the array
2. concat each element with previous one if the string length is less than the maximum allowed value (e.g. 13)
3. push the concatenated string into another array (e.g. $words2[])
4. return the $words2 array as the result

So you can use the function `wrapLines($words1,13)`, as follows:

```
<?php

function wrapLines($words, $maxLineLength) {
$words2=[];
$words1=$words;

$index=0;
$maxlength=$maxLineLength;
$injectstring="";
$olstring="";

while  ($index < count($words1)){

    if ($injectstring==""){
       $tempstring=$words1[$index];
    }else{
       $tempstring="-".$words1[$index];
    }


   $oldstring=$injectstring;

  if (strlen($injectstring) < $maxlength) {
      $injectstring=$injectstring . $tempstring;
  }

  if (strlen($injectstring) == $maxlength) {
       $words2[]= $injectstring ; 
       $injectstring=""; 
   }

  if (strlen($injectstring) > $maxlength) {     
       $words2[]= $oldstring ; 
       $injectstring=$words1[$index]; 
   }
$index++;
}
   $words2[]= $injectstring ."<br>"; 
return($words2); 
}



$words1 = [ "The", "day", "began", "as", "still", "as", "the",
          "night", "abruptly", "lighted", "with", "brilliant",
          "flame" ];

print_r(wrapLines($words1,13));
          ?>
```